# How to apply different restrictions on the same complex type depending on parent tag

Tags: xml, xsd

I would like to reach the scenario showed below, in which I have the same element (in this case component) with different parents. I want to add a restriction only to the first level of <**component**>. For example I want to add the restriction that the color (under components) can be only yellow or green but the color under <**component-set**> could be any color.

```
<components>
    <component color="yellow"/>
    <component color="green"/>
    <component-set>
      <component color="black"/>  
    </component-set>
  </xs:complexType>
</components>
```

this is my current xsd and I'm not supposed to edit complex Type or element name.

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://../custom.xsd" xmlns="http://../custom.xsd">

 <xs:complexType name="componentType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="color" use="required"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="component-setType" mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="componentType" name="component" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="componentsType">
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
      <xs:element type="componentType" name="component"/>
      <xs:element type="component-setType" name="component-set"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already using local element declarations (`xs:element` with a `name` attribute appearing within the content model of a complex type). Two local element declarations appearing in different content models can have different types; just because both elements are called `"component"` doesn't mean they both need to have type `"componentType"`.

Comment: Is it possible to have the same type and apply these restrictions only to one?

Comment: No, if there are different restrictions then by definition they are different types.